# Stupid SQL error with no leads

Tags: php, mysql, fetch

Ok, I can't figure out why this doesn't work at all.

```
$get_data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM chatbox ORDER BY ID WHERE message = 'bla'");
while($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_data)) {
*blablabla code*
}
```

This does NOT work. It gives me a

> "Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource" error. (with line number ofcourse)

When I remove the `"WHERE message = 'bla'"` part, it works fine. Tryed with and without ' things around bla and around messages. Message field does excist in my DB, so does the entry bla. Tryed it even with the ID field in my DB, with number 1, does not work at all. What is wrong with this simple line of code. Tryed to look almost everywhere, can't figure it out...

Comment: Stop using the **deprecated and as of PHP7 removed** mysql_* functions. Migrate to PDO and start using Prepared Statements.

Comment: if you are going to still use the outdated `mysql_*` functions, you might as well learn to use `mysql_error()`, ie. `$get_data = mysql_query(...[your query code]...) or die(mysql_error()));` to learn to debug yourself.

Comment: Thanks Sean, I will add that die thingie to my future code. Unfortunately it didn't give the solution. (problem has been solved btw) And it's just a hobby project with older software. So it's no big problem for me, if I use outdated code like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `WHERE` clause after ORDER BY, it can not be work for you.

**Modified Query:**

```
SELECT * FROM chatbox WHERE message = 'bla' ORDER BY ID
```

You need to follow this sequence when you crease **MYSQL SELECT Statement**:

> SELECT .. COLUMNS .. FROM .. WHERE .. ORDER

**[SELECT Manual Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html)**

**Side Note:**

Please use `mysqli_*` or `PDO` instead of `mysql_*` because this extension deprecated and not available in PHP 7.

Comment: Thanks alot Devpro and Mr. Engineer! That did the trick! Finaly I can go further.

Comment: @Pietertje: no problem, errors cant be stupid bro... now. chose the best answer and mark as accepted.. will help to others. Read this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

Your query is wrong. You are using order by before where condition.

Try this query : `"SELECT * FROM chatbox WHERE message = 'bla' ORDER BY ID"`

And also migrate from `mysql_*` to `mysqli_*`.